# titanium iphone app dev

Tags: iphone, titanium

I have started working on titanium for iphone dev but i am bit confused about the file structure. The only file that i can see is app.js in Resources folder. Which is helpful in creating interface design.

**For instance:**
1- If i want to show the current time on my application main page, where i can initialize my code.
2- If i want to add some js functionality onload, how can i add that js file or call it on my application load.

I will be very thank full if any body give some helpfull links for learning as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appcelerator recently added a "Getting Started" guide in the developer center. I highly recommend going through those articles. There's not much good documentation around Titanium but their getting better.

http://guides.appcelerator.com/en/getting_started.html

As for adding current time and listening to events... you can find some great examples in the KitchenSink application (https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink) or Tweetanium (https://github.com/appcelerator/tweetanium). I usually keep these projects open on the side and search the code base for examples since the API docs on the website are a bit dated.

I hope that helps.